# Linux shell - parse date in odd formats

Tags: bash, date

Is there any way to use standard tools (not programming scripts) to parse the date in custom, odd format?

I've got a start script (bash) that should handle the output of the program, that contains dates with very odd formatting (like Jan, 4, 2021, 1:20:30 PM - which would be a pattern like "MMM, d, yyyy, h:mm:ss a".

It would be possible to extract the tokens with sed or awk, but processing them is a nightmare, especially month shortcuts (they are in the same language like system, but that language can be installation-specific) or hours (need to check AM/PM token and add 12 if it's PM).

'date' apparently doesn't support that, but maybe some shell extension or toolkit package? Or I'm out of luck and I need to parse this crappy format token by token with sed/cut/awk?

This what I've tried was to do `touch -d "Date"` after removing the commas (so that I can compare dates with `[[ file1 -ot file2 ]]`, but the problem is, that touch has ignored the TIME part, and `ls -lh` has shown, that the year was set in place of time, and the result of the comparison was therefore invalid.

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus I've searched for linux parse date pattern, parse custom / odd format, but the working examples I've found were python...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert date with GNU `date` and `bash`:

```
d="Jan, 4, 2021, 1:20:30 PM"

IFS=',:' read mon day year hour min sec a <<<"$d"
date -d "$mon $day $year $hour:$min:$sec $a" '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Output:

```
2021-01-04 13:20:30
```